# Rails generate subsclass doesn't create new table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are the commands I use to generate rails models:

```
rails g scaffold fruit name variety colour
rails g scaffold vegetable harvested_at:time --parent Fruit
```

The 2nd command was executed without error but it does not work, it only creates a model without the extra attribute, and there is no db migration generated either. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord supports mapping inheritance hierarchies to a single table. You can not create extra fields in your database when you create a child class from parent AR class in this case.
You can see more about scaffolding, if you write

```
rails g scaffold --help
```

in your terminal. For AR models you can see this:

```
ActiveRecord options:
      [--migration], [--no-migration]    # Indicates when to generate migration
                                         # Default: true
      [--timestamps], [--no-timestamps]  # Indicates when to generate timestamps
                                         # Default: true
      [--parent=PARENT]                  # The parent class for the generated model
      [--indexes], [--no-indexes]        # Add indexes for references and belongs_to columns
                                         # Default: true   -t, [--test-framework=NAME]            # Test framework to be invoked
                                         # Default: test_unit
```

This is full list of options that you can use.

Comment: I see, I know we can modify models/migration files to do this but is there a rails command to generate a subclass model with extra fields?

Comment: yeah thank you, I did a few research and just find out it's ok to have extra field that we do not use in our model when opting for sti approach to do inheritance.